# is AutoResetEvent waitOne() function what I am looking for?

Tags: c#

I am new on this forum but I have always checked it out and I appreciate it very much. 
I must say in the beginning that I am not a very skilled or knowledgable software programmer and for the past days I am stuck on a problem. I have a barcode reader on my COM1 port. I connect, I write "TRIGGER", it returns with(hopefully) "OK", when I have the OK, then I send a "READ", and it comes back with a big line with some fields. So here is right now how my code looks like; (the code is mainly like this. I didn`t write it all but the serialPort and waitHandle stuff is like below)

in SerialPortExample class,

```
public AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
public string Read()
{
  for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    this._serialPort.Write("TRIGGER" + Convert.ToChar(0));
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
    // a couple lines of stuff
    this._serialPort.Write("GETSTRINGRESULTS" + Convert.ToChar(0));
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
    if (OBarcode.ReadStatus == ReadStatus.SUCCESS) {
      return OBarcode.BarcodeString;
    }
  }

  return "";
}
```

this is raised when some answer from serialPort

```
void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  try {
    string value = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
    ...
    // stuff
    waitHandle.Set();
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

in the form with behind a button click, I open the connection, do the Read(), Close() the connection and so on. I have seen this AutoResetEvent online and decided to use. When I click the button for the first time, everything runs smooth, but, if I click the button again. which reoopens the closed connection and does the read again, this time the WaitOne() doesn`t wait.

I would appreciate very much appreciate your help. How should I normally handle this? I am doing something seriously wrong.

Comment: Are you resetting the waitHandle back to false after the first WaitOne() is triggered?

Comment: I tried waitHandle.Reset() but nothing changed. I can't pinpoint in which situations it waits and which it doesn't. When I debug line by line, it seems to wait, but when I jump around (debugging without line by line) or start without debugging, it doesn't wait.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with serial ports but normally you would do `write(); var response = read();`. No events there. The difference is that you pull data when you want it, it does not get pushed to you.

Comment: how should it be normally handled, without thinking of barcode reader, but an event? When an operation needs to wait for the result?

Comment: @EduardoMango Try: waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

Comment: yes I did. Didn`t work again. I realized that when I click on the button which opens the connection, reads the barcode and closes, then the waitOne()`s don`t work.

Comment: from the doc.. If a thread calls WaitOne while the AutoResetEvent is in the signaled state, the thread does not block. The AutoResetEvent releases the thread immediately and returns to the non-signaled state.  try using Reset() after first WaitOne()

Comment: You cannot use ReadExisting(), it normally only returns 1 or 2 characters.  Setup the scanner and the SerialPort.NewLine property so you can use ReadLine().  And don't call Close(), there is no point in allowing another app to steal the serial port.

Comment: I agree with Hans, you probably have an issue with ReadExisting(), check the API documentation, ReadExisting may not be reading all string at once

Comment: I have changed it to ReadLine(), but I actually hold the string and not set the waitHande until I receive the terminator (CR LF) and done with parsing. What I have seen is that, if I Close the connection after I am done with reading, and click on the button again, (which does all the reading and closes), then I have the problem with waitHandle. If everytime I create a new SerialPortExample object behind the button click, I don't have any problems. But I have no idea what happens after first read so that my waitHandle doesn't work anymore. If I remove the Close(), then it works just fine.

Comment: But I don't know if it is good to keep the connection open at all times.

Comment: I have found the solution. It is my stupidity. I had another event that sets the wait handle when I'm done parsing. So I just got rid of it and set the waitHandle directly.